# Make image height responsive

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have an image in my site which it's height is bigger than it's width.

The problem is that in small screens the image is very tall and I want to limit it somehow and set the `max-height` to be the height of the screen (responsive).

I'm using Bootstrap so I used `.img-responsive` class but it doesn't work.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dqsLt4sa/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`vh` unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) for that.

```
max-height: 100vh;
```

To specify that no image should be larger than the screen use the following CSS

```
img {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make it work in IE8?

Comment: You can use a polyfill like [vminpoly](https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly) or a JavaScript solution like [vunit](http://joaocunha.github.io/vunit/).